# AngularJS: $stateProvider move code to template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have next `view.html` for example:

```html
<div>
  <h1> Block 1 </h1>
  <div>
    <h1> Block 2 </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

in `js` file

```
$stateProvider
        .state('blocks', {
            url: '/blocks',
            template: require('./view.html'),
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        })
```

And it works. But i want to move `"Block 2"` to template. And i created `./units/block2.html`

view.html:

```
<div>
  <h1> Block 1 </h1>
  <div ui-view="block2"/>
</div
```

js file:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('blocks', {
         url: '/blocks',
         template: require('./view.html'),
         controller: 'MainController',
         controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    })
    .state('blocks.block2', {   
        views: {
            'block2@blocks.block2': {
                templateUrl: "./units/block2.html"
            }
        }
    })
}
```

What is wrong? I try next ways - and i can not see content from block2:

```
template: require('./units/block2.html')

'block2': {
         template: require('./units/block2.html')
```

Comment: Could you reproduce a working version of this in https://plnkr.co/ and then also create a version of the problem? That would help us debug your question.

Comment: where is the controller for block2 state?

Comment: Why did you abandon your plan to use `ng-include`?